# Trying to create simple component with React-JSS

Tags: css, reactjs, jss

I'm trying to create a simple component, styled with React-JSS:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createUseStyles, useTheme } from 'react-jss';

import { useSessionState, useSessionDispatch } from '../../../contexts/SessionContext';

const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  messageSuccess: {
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  }
});

const SystemMessage = () => {
  const dispatch = useSessionDispatch();

  const theme = useTheme();
  const classes = useStyles({theme});

  return (
    <div className={classes.messageSuccess}>
      abcd
    </div>
  );
}

export default SystemMessage;
```

Upon running it, I get this message:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
const useStyles = createUseStyles({
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should update your react-css version to 10.0.0